# Laravel: DB::transaction() in try catch not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions

I am using manual DB transactions in my controller.

```
public function exportUsers(){

  DB::beginTransaction();
  try{
    $data = new \App\Models\User();
    $excelData = $data->getMemberData();
    $reportGeneratedOn = date('dMY');
    $report_file_name = 'All_Members_'.$reportGeneratedOn.'.xls';
    DB::table('settings')->where('id',1)->update(['user_export_status_id'=>2]);
    $excelHTML = view('administrator.member.excel',compact('excelData'))->render();

    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
    $spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($excelHTML);
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
    $fileName = md5('allmembers_'. microtime()).".xls";
    $path = storage_path('app/temp/');
    $writer->save( $path . $fileName );
    $excel_file_content = file_get_contents( $path . $fileName );
    $data = $this->S3Upload($fileName , env('S3_MEMBERS_EXPORT_PATH'), env('S3_MEMBERS_EXPORT_URL'), $excel_file_content,$report_file_name );
   if ( $data['status'] ){
    DB::table('settings')->where('id',1)->update(['user_export_status_id'=>3]);
    DB::table('settings')->where('id',1)->update(['user_export_path'=>$data['preSignedUrl']]);
   if( is_file($path . $fileName) ) {
   @unlink( $path . $fileName );
   }
}

  DB::commit();
  return response()->json(['error' => 0, 'code' => 200, 'message' => 'Please download the generated excel.','status'=>3, 'report_url' => $data['preSignedUrl']], 200);
}
  catch(\Exception $e){

   DB::rollBack();
  return response()->json(['error' => 1, 'code' => 200, 'message' => 'An error occured while generating the report.'.$e->getMessage().' : '.$e->getFile().'-'.$e->getLine()], 200);
 }
}
```

But using this I got an error like below

> Error : An error occured while generating the report.DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 2855 :
>   C:\wamp64\www\O2X\Trunk\Web\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html.php-619

My database has a user_export_status_id field which at first has value 1..When an export starts it get updated as 2. But after I got error, it is not roll backed to 1. Dataabse still has value 2.

Comment: you should try this https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/ as u r using laravel

Comment: Why MaatWebsite? Can't we do Db transactions for any other excel libraries in Laravel.

Comment: @Opps  maatwebsite have good feature and clean code that's why